# List length versus dictionary length in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a REST request that can return one or more items in JSON.

When it returns one element, it looks like this:
`{1,2,3}`, i.e., a dictionary;

When it returns more than one element, it looks like this:
`[{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}]` i.e., a list of dictionaries.

In order to access the data, I need to test if there is one or several results. But the problem is that:

```
len ([{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}]) == len ({1,2,3}) == 3.
```

How can I differ both structures?

Comment: `{1,2,3}` is a set, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a= {1,2,3}

b= [{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}]

print type(a)

print type(b)
```

Output ->

```
<type 'set'>
<type 'list'>
```

You can use that type based logic in an if statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the distinction between set and list.

```
if isinstance(result, set):
   # only one result
else:
   # multiple results
```